# $m$-primary ideal and $M\otimes_{A} A/m \neq 0$

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules

> Let $A$ be a commutative local ring with maximal ideal $m$. Let $M$ be a (not necessarily finitely generated) $A$-module. Let $x_{1},\dots,x_{n}$ be an $M$-regular sequence such that $\operatorname{Ann}(M/(x_{1},...,x_{n})M)$ is proper and $m$-primary. Then  $m(M/(x_{1},...,x_{n})M)\neq M/(x_{1},...,x_{n})M$ and  $M\otimes_{A} A/m \neq 0$.

I can't prove this fact .

Comment: A is not notherian . If A is notherian , is it easy to show ?

Comment: You can reduce the problem to $n=0$, and then you should prove that if $Ann(M)$ is $m$-primary it follows $M\ne mM$. I'm afraid this is false. Try an example of a non-noetherian local ring of dimension $0$ with $m=m^2$. However, if $m$ or $M$ is f.g., then the claim holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collecting the observations above by user121097 into an answer:

Let $I = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$. Then $m(M/IM) \ne M/IM$ iff $(M/IM) \otimes_A A/m \ne 0$, but $M/IM \otimes_A A/m \cong M \otimes_A A/I \otimes_A A/m \cong M \otimes_A A/(I+m) \cong M \otimes_A A/m$, so asking when $m(M/IM) \ne M/IM$ and $M \otimes_A A/m \ne 0$ are equivalent. Thus replacing $M$ with $M/IM$, we may as well assume $I = 0$, and ask if $M \ne mM$.

If $M$ is finitely generated, then $M \ne mM$ by Nakayama. If $m$ is finitely generated, then since $\text{Ann}(M)$ is $m$-primary, $m^t \subseteq \text{Ann}(M)$ for some $t$, so $m^tM = 0$. Thus if $M = mM$, then $M = mM = m^2M = \ldots = m^tM = 0$, contradicting $\text{Ann}(M)$ being proper.

On the other hand, if neither $m$ nor $M$ is finitely generated, then it is possible that $M = mM$: taking $M = m$, any local ring of dimension zero with $m = m^2 \ne 0$ gives an example. An explicit such ring is $k[x, x^{1/2}, x^{1/4}, \ldots]/(x)$, i.e. $k[x_1, x_2, \ldots]/(x_1, x_{i+1}^2-x_i \mid i \ge 1)$.

Comment: Good example, thank you